# Google Charts - Labels not matching data

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

I am building a statistical view for a client's booking system. They'd like to see which activities were booked in specific months.

I'm using Google Charts for this but the data doesn't match the labels being produced - i.e. the correct data is being attached to the wrong activity.

I've verified via the database and print_r's that the product IDs are being pulled from the database successfully and attached to the correct activity ID number, and that the number and order of labels matches the number and order of activities, which they are:

```
 $sql = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM products ORDER BY ProductID ASC";
 $set = $link->query($sql);
 while($row = $set->fetch_row())
 {
  $arrLabels[$row[0]] = "#".$row[0].": ".$row[1];
 }
 ksort($arrLabels);

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM bookings_products INNER JOIN bookings ON bookings.BookingID=bookings_products.BookingProductBooking WHERE BookingConfirmed>0 ORDER BY BookingProductProduct ASC";
 $set = $link->query($sql);
 while($row = $set->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
 {
  $dm = substr($row['BookingDate'],5,2); // To get the month from YYYY-MM-DD dates
  $arrPeople[$dm][$row['BookingProductProduct']] = $arrPeople[$dm][$row['BookingProductProduct']] + (1 * $row['BookingGroupSize']);
 }
 ksort($arrPeople);

 echo "<pre>"; print_r($arrLabels); echo "</pre>";
 echo "<hr/>";
 echo "<pre>"; print_r($arrPeople); echo "</pre>";
```

I then build the Google Charts JS code like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart()
 {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   [<?php foreach($arrLabels as $p) { ?>'<?php echo str_replace("'","\'",$p); ?>', <?php } ?>{ role: 'annotation' } ],
   ['Jan', <?php foreach($arrLabels as $k=>$v) { ?><?php echo $arrPeople['01'][$k] ?: '0'; ?>, <?php } ?>],
   ['Feb', <?php foreach($arrLabels as $k=>$v) { ?><?php echo $arrPeople['02'][$k] ?: '0'; ?>, <?php } ?>],
   ['Mar', <?php foreach($arrLabels as $k=>$v) { ?><?php echo $arrPeople['03'][$k] ?: '0'; ?>, <?php } ?>],
   ['Apr', <?php foreach($arrLabels as $k=>$v) { ?><?php echo $arrPeople['04'][$k] ?: '0'; ?>, <?php } ?>],
   ['May', <?php foreach($arrLabels as $k=>$v) { ?><?php echo $arrPeople['05'][$k] ?: '0'; ?>, <?php } ?>],
   ['Jun', <?php foreach($arrLabels as $k=>$v) { ?><?php echo $arrPeople['06'][$k] ?: '0'; ?>, <?php } ?>],
   ['Jul', <?php foreach($arrLabels as $k=>$v) { ?><?php echo $arrPeople['07'][$k] ?: '0'; ?>, <?php } ?>],
   ['Aug', <?php foreach($arrLabels as $k=>$v) { ?><?php echo $arrPeople['08'][$k] ?: '0'; ?>, <?php } ?>],
   ['Sep', <?php foreach($arrLabels as $k=>$v) { ?><?php echo $arrPeople['09'][$k] ?: '0'; ?>, <?php } ?>],
   ['Oct', <?php foreach($arrLabels as $k=>$v) { ?><?php echo $arrPeople['10'][$k] ?: '0'; ?>, <?php } ?>],
   ['Nov', <?php foreach($arrLabels as $k=>$v) { ?><?php echo $arrPeople['11'][$k] ?: '0'; ?>, <?php } ?>],
   ['Dec', <?php foreach($arrLabels as $k=>$v) { ?><?php echo $arrPeople['12'][$k] ?: '0'; ?>, <?php } ?>],
  ]);

  var options = {
   title: 'Product popularity by month - Number of people (based on activity date)',
   isStacked: true,
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart3b'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
 }
 </script>
 <div id="chart3b" style="margin-top:15px; width: 900px; height: 500px; border:solid 1px #000;"></div><hr/>
```

You can see (via a static HTML copy-and-paste of the dynamic PHP output) the Google Chart produced here: http://www.stuart-pinfold.co.uk/stats.htm

You'll notice that activity #50 (Santa Experience) which had 195 visitors in December (month 12) is being assigned in the chart to activity #51 ("Zombie Air Rifle, Zombie Pistol, 10 Clay Shoots") instead.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Maybe you're forgetting that an array should start in 0 and in your code is starting for 01 : <?php echo $arrPeople['01'][$k] ?: '0'; ?>, <?php } ?> , another thing is .. why you don't try to have more clean view and separate the php in javascript ? i mean for example ...try to do an ajax call and pas this data var to google draw's method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first column of values is the month name, but your first cell at your headers row isn't a "month" label.

If you look at your example the activity #50 (Santa experience), you can see that the value of this label is 1 step to the left in the graph.

Make sure that instead of

```
['#5: Special Offer Ultimate Shooting Package ', '#6: CPSA Shotgun Skills Course',.....],
['Jan', 0,....
```

it looks like

```
['Months', '#5: Special Offer Ultimate Shooting Package ',.....],
['Jan', 0,.....
```

and everything should work just fine.

Comment: When I do this the Chrome Console complains "Uncaught Error: Row 0 has 86 columns, but must have 87". New version at http://www.stuart-pinfold.co.uk/stats2.htm with this change.

Comment: Remove the `annotation` column, {role: 'annotation'}.

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/5ydqbmjt/1/).